# How to return an image from wwwroot?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I'm trying to return an image stored inside `wwwwroot/images` folder, this is the structure:

[image]

Inside the `View` I have the following tag:

```
<img src="@Url.Action("GetAvatar", "User", new { username = User.Identity.Name })" />
```

as you can see for display the image it simply call `GetAvatar` method from `User` controller passing the username as parameter.

The method have the following configuration:

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult GetAvatar(string username)
{
   User user = _repo.GetUser(username);

   if(user.UserDetail != null)
      return File(user.UserDetail?.UserPhoto, "image/png");

   //The user has no custom image, will displayed the default.
   string root = Path.Combine(_env.WebRootPath, "images");

   return File(Path.Combine(root, "avatar_default.png"), "image/png");
}
```

the firtst part of the method that retrieve the image from the database works, but the last part which try to get the image from the `wwwroot` folder doesn't work. Infact when I load the `View` I get the broked thumbnail which mean not found.

I'm also injected the `IHostingEnvironment` for access to `wwwroot` folder.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `File` method you're using has the following signature:

```
public VirtualFileResult File (string virtualPath, string contentType);
```

As its name suggests, the first parameter here represents the *virtual* path of the file you want to serve; not the *physical* path. By default, this means you need to provide a path that is essentially just *relative* to the `wwwroot` folder. In your example, the path would be `images/avatar_default.png`. With this, there's no need for `Path.Combine` or `IHostingEnvironment` in your example. Here's the updated version:

```
[HttpGet]
public FileResult GetAvatar(string username)
{
   User user = _repo.GetUser(username);

   if(user.UserDetail != null)
      return File(user.UserDetail?.UserPhoto, "image/png");

   return File("images/avatar_default.png", "image/png");
}
```